# Parsing a zipcode boundary geojson file based on a condition, then appending to a a new json file if condition is met

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, geojson

I have a geojson file of zipcode boundaries.

```
with open('zip_geo.json') as f: 
    gj = geojson.load(f)
```

---

```
gj['features'][0]['properties']
```

Prints out;

```
{'STATEFP10': '36',
 'ZCTA5CE10': '12205',
 'GEOID10': '3612205',
 'CLASSFP10': 'B5',
 'MTFCC10': 'G6350',
 'FUNCSTAT10': 'S',
 'ALAND10': 40906445,
 'AWATER10': 243508,
 'INTPTLAT10': '+42.7187855',
 'INTPTLON10': '-073.8292399',
 'PARTFLG10': 'N'}
```

I also have a pandas dataframe with one of the fields being the zipcode.

I want to create a new geojson file only if the 'ZCTA5CEO' value of the specific element is present in the zipcode column of my dataframe.

How would I go about doing this?

I was thinking of something like; (This is pseudo code)

```
new_dict = {}

for index,item in enumerate(gj):
    if item['features'][index]['properties']['ZCTACE10'] in df['zipcode']:
        new_dict += item
```

The syntax of the code above is obviously wrong, but I am not sure how to parse though multiple nested dictionaries and append the results to a new dictionary.

---

Link to the geojson file : https://github.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON/blob/master/ny_new_york_zip_codes_geo.min.json

In short I want to remove all the elements relating to the zipcodes that are not there in the zipcode column in my dataframe.

Comment: It's unclear from your example how your file and gj is structured. Please post more of it. And is your output a single zipcode dictionary or do you want a new list of dictionaries? Or is the new file just dictionaries separated by commas or new lines?

Comment: The geojson file is too large that theres not enough space to post even 1 element of that, here's the link to the file.https://github.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON/blob/master/ny_new_york_zip_codes_geo.min.json 

Basically I want to keep the json file the same, just remove the zipcodes that are not in my dataframe's zipcode column

Comment: each zip code element has a properties and geometry associated with it. Do want to save all that stuff as well, or really just wanting to keep the properties. It's a bit of a different exercise depending on what you really want for the output. also paste in the first 10 rows of the df so I can see how the zip code column is formatted/referenced.

Comment: @JonathanLeon, I want to add all the elements (properties and geometry) to the new gj, as long as that zipcode is there in my dataframe. The zipcode column is just called zipcode. Formatted as string.

Removing all elements of a zipcode not in the dataframe would do the exact same thing.

Comment: How many zip codes in your data frame? Just New York or all states.?

Comment: My dataframe has around 13 zipcodes, from Monroe County in New York. I want to produce a choropleth map using zipcode boundaries. I can do that once, I have a geoJSON file. However I can't find a geojson only Monroe County, So the next best thing I could find was all of new york state, and just removed the zipcodes not in my dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. just update your ziplist. then you can save the new json to a local file

```
ziplist = ['12205', '14719', '12193', '12721'] #list of zips in your dataframe

url='https://github.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON/raw/master/ny_new_york_zip_codes_geo.min.json'
gj =  requests.get(url).json()

inziplist = []
for  ft in gj['features']:
    if ft['properties']['ZCTA5CE10'] in ziplist:
        print(ft['properties']['ZCTA5CE10'])
        inziplist.append(ft)
print(len(inziplist))        

new_zip_json = {}
new_zip_json['type'] = 'FeatureCollection'
new_zip_json['features'] = inziplist
new_zip_json  = json.dumps(new_zip_json)
```

Comment: Thanks man, you know whats funny, I wrote almost the exact same code, it wasn't working because the entries in my dataframe were actually int64 not strings, real programmer moment.